# Stored Procedure saying rows affected but nothing is commiting

Tags: sql-server

I'm making a stored procedure where I'm inputting an employee and a manager. If the manager isn't already in the employee table I need to add him and then I can add the employee. If the manager is already in the table then I just have the Manager's `EmployeeID` as the `ManagerID`

[image: Here is my employee table to help]

Here is my Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateEmployee (
    @DepartmentID INT,
    @EmployeeFirstName NVARCHAR(25),
    @EmployeeLastName NVARCHAR(25),
    @Salary MONEY = 30000,
    @ManagerFirstName NVARCHAR(25),
    @ManagerLastName NVARCHAR(25)
    )

    AS 
    BEGIN;
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SET XACT_ABORT ON;
        DECLARE @ManagerID INT;
        SELECT @ManagerID = dbo.GetEmployeeID (@ManagerFirstName, @ManagerLastName);
        IF (@ManagerID = NULL)
        BEGIN;
            INSERT INTO dbo.Employees (FirstName, LastName)
            VALUES (@ManagerFirstName, @ManagerLastName)
            SELECT @ManagerID = dbo.GetEmployeeID(@ManagerFirstName, @ManagerLastName)

            INSERT INTO dbo.Employees (DepartmentID, FirstName, LastName, Salary, ManagerEmployeeID)
            VALUES (@DepartmentID, @EmployeeFirstName, @EmployeeLastName, @Salary, @ManagerID)
        END;


        ELSE 
        BEGIN;
            INSERT INTO dbo.Employees (DepartmentID, FirstName, LastName, Salary, ManagerEmployeeID)
            VALUES (@DepartmentID, @EmployeeFirstName, @EmployeeLastName, @Salary, @ManagerID)
        END;
    END;
GO
```

When I test my procedure, it adds the Employee fine but never adds the manager I input.

Here's how I'm testing:

```
    EXECUTE dbo.CreateEmployee 
        @DepartmentID = 1,
        @EmployeeFirstName = 'Brock',
        @EmployeeLastName = 'Rigby',
        @Salary = 120000,
        @ManagerFirstName = 'Bob',
        @ManagerLastName = 'Barker'
```

If anyone could help me out that would be great. If you need any more information just comment below.

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated RDBMS. MySQL And SQL Server completely different products. From the image, this appears to be SQL Server, (as that is clearly SSMS), so I have removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: Brock, in sql server, to check for NULL, you've to do ManagerId is null instead of ManagerId = null. That may be the problem.

Comment: `IF (@ManagerID = NULL)` - this will *always* be `false`.  Nothing can ever `= NULL`.  You need to use `IF (@ManagerID IS NULL)`

Comment: Im going to hide my code to anyone in the future since this is a school project, I could get int trouble for putting my stuff out there, but thankyou to everyone who helped me solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Brock, in sql server, to check for NULL, you have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` instead of @ManagerId = null (this is a syntax when you need to set value to NULL). That may be the problem.

```
IF (@ManagerID IS NULL)-- this! you would never enter if block with @managerId = null
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO dbo.Employees (FirstName, LastName)
    VALUES (@ManagerFirstName, @ManagerLastName)
    SELECT @ManagerID = dbo.GetEmployeeID(@ManagerFirstName, @ManagerLastName)

    INSERT INTO dbo.Employees (DepartmentID, FirstName, LastName, Salary, ManagerEmployeeID)
    VALUES (@DepartmentID, @EmployeeFirstName, @EmployeeLastName, @Salary, @ManagerID)
END;


ELSE 
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO dbo.Employees (DepartmentID, FirstName, LastName, Salary, ManagerEmployeeID)
    VALUES (@DepartmentID, @EmployeeFirstName, @EmployeeLastName, @Salary, @ManagerID)
END;
```

Comment: The solution is correct, but the reasoning is misleading.  I wouldn't say that it's the syntax for setting the value.  It *is* the correct syntax for checking equality, but due to the nature of `NULL`, nothing can ever equal it - not even another `NULL` - so for those you must use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Well that makes sense! Thanks Siyual, didn't think of it that way.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was looking for a more complex reason instead of the stupid IS NULL

Comment: You're welcome. I use 'print' statements when I am debugging my stored proc, especially the ones that has many conditionals. May be it can help you in future debugging - just write something like print 'inside managerId is null' etc.

Comment: Yea I'll keep that in mind in the future, Thanks again!